# What does the ocaml type 'a. 'a -> 'a mean?

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml

In the ocaml language specification, there's a short section:

```
poly-typexpr ::= typexpr
               | { ' ident }+ . typexpr
```

There's no explanation in the text, and the only instance of `poly-typexpr` is in defining a method type:

```
method-type ::= method-name : poly-typexpr
```

What does this allow me to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`poly-typexpr` is also allowed as the type of a record field (see [Section 6.8.1](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual016.html#s:type-defs)). These are commonly called "existential types," though there is [some debate on that point](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.caml.general/36843). Using a polymorphic type in this way changes the scope of the type variable. For example, compare the types:

```
type 'a t = { f : 'a -> int; }
type u = { g : 'a. 'a -> int; }
```

`t` is really a family of types, one for each possible value of `'a`. Each value of type `'a t` must have a field `f` with the type `'a -> int`. For example:

```
# let x = { f = fun i -> i+1; } ;;
val x : int t = {f = <fun>}
# let y = { f = String.length; } ;;
val y : string t = {f = <fun>}
```

In comparison, `u` is a single type. Each value of type `u` must have a field `g` with the type `'a -> int` for *any* `'a`. For example:

```
# let z = { g = fun _ -> 0; } ;;
val z : u = {g = <fun>}
```

Note here that `g` doesn't depend on the type of its input at all; if it did, it wouldn't have the type `'a. 'a -> int`. For example:

```
# let x2 = { g = fun i -> i+1; } ;;
This field value has type int -> int which is less general than 'a. 'a -> int
```

Answer (score 1):

See [section 3.11 "Polymorphic methods"](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual005.html#htoc29). Scroll down to "Of course the constraint may also be an explicit method type..."